# Need to solve undefined index error in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to schedule posts to a FB Page with laravel 5 and facebook SDK.

I need to choose between post a comment **now** or schedule it for later.

With my code bellow I am able to schedule my post. But if I want to post immediately an exception is thrown:

> "ErrorException in FacebookController.php line 118: Undefined index: pub_schedule". Line 118 is "if ($input['pub_schedule'] !=1)"

What's wrong here?

#### This is my Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Veröffentlichen auf</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
              {!! Form::label('pub_facebook', 'Facebook') !!}
              {!! Form::checkbox('pub_facebook') !!}

              {!! Form::label('pub_website', 'Meiner Webseite') !!}
              {!! Form::checkbox('pub_website') !!}

          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Veröffentlichen am</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">

            {!! Form::label('pub_now', 'Sofort Veröffentlichen') !!}
            {!! Form::checkbox('pub_now') !!}

            {!! Form::label('pub_schedule', 'Für Später Planen') !!}
            {!! Form::checkbox('pub_schedule') !!}
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('published_at', 'Veröffentlichungsdatum') !!}
        {!! Form::input('datetime','published_at', Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
      </div>
```

#### This Is my ArticlesController:

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request) {


  // Only if the user is a FB user then this function will execute.
  if(Auth::user()->facebook_user_id != 0)
  {
    //Checkbox Publish on FB
    if($request->pub_facebook !=0) {
      //Radio Button Schedule
      if ($request->pub_schedule!=0) {
        if(strtotime($request->get('published_at')) < strtotime("+11 minutes") ){
          // send a message to user to change the scheduled time.
          return 'Please schedule you post again: +11 Minutes';
        }
      } else {
        $graphNode = FacebookController::postToFBPage($request->all());
      }
    }
  }
```

#### This is My FacebookController:

```
public static function postToFBPage($input, $page_id = '')
{

    $page_id == '' ? $page_id = '' : $page_id;

    // Creating a new FB object.
    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_ID'),
        'app_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'),
        'default_graph_version' => env('FACEBOOK_GRAPH_VERSION'),
        ]);


  // Sample and some of the possible fields that can be send when posting to FB.
  // $linkData = [
  //   'link' => 'absolute link here',
  //   'message' => 'Main body content here',
  //   'picture' => 'path/to/the/image.jpg'
  //   ];


  //to post immediately

  if ($input['pub_schedule'] !=1) {
    $linkData = [
    'message' => $input['title'] . "\n" . $input['body'] . "\n" . $input['price']
    ];

   // to schedule a post to fb
  } else {
    $linkData = [
    'message' => $input['title'] . "\n" . $input['body'] . "\n" . $input['price'] ,
      "published" => false,
      'scheduled_publish_time' => strtotime($input['published_at']),
    ];
  }
```

Comment: Make sure you are posting all the required variables you are going to use, else you can check if your post variable is set or not as given in the answer

Comment: check whether the variable is actually set or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in your form, the field is optional. Hence, the value will not be set. Do something like this:

```
if (isset($input['pub_schedule']) && $input['pub_schedule'] !=1) {
    $linkData = [
    'message' => $input['title'] . "\n" . $input['body'] . "\n" . $input['price']
    ];
}
```